# How to avoid QSS memory leak with :image selector?

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, qtstylesheets

I few days search the source on the memory leak in my software and at least found it.

So steps:
I create the GUI application, add image to the .qrc, create form in Qt Designer, add QPushButton there and in the styleSheet property write

```
#closeButton{ image: url(:/system/images/White/Close.png); }
```

(the button named as "closeButton")

Without style sheet that I add the program works fine, with style sheet - I receive memory leak.

So how to avoid memory leak in this case?

Comment: How do you know it leaks? Do you create a button and destroy it in a loop?

Comment: @vahancho , I used Catch2 library. I create test case and it automatically check the memory leak. I just create app, my widget, show my widget and run. Next I close the widget from sysmenu, after this the application finished. And at this point I could see if memory leak exist

Comment: It's not a memory leak in its classic definition. Your application is terminated, and OS will most probably free the memory, unless it's a specific OS.

Comment: So do you mean that this leak only once and in following execution will not continue leak?

Answer (score 0):

Objects that survive till the process termination aren't necessarily memory leaks, and the tool won't be able to tell you which ones are memory leaks and which aren't. Memory leaks are usually only the allocations that are made multiple times from the same program location, and never get freed. Even then, it may not always be the case. Leak detection requires a purpose-made test harness that repeats a series of operations that are supposed not to leave behind memory allocated at any given program location more than once. If you then notice that, with increasing number of operations, the number of memory blocks left behind increases, you likely have a real leak. Ideally, the test harness should take snapshots of allocated memory blocks after each "operation cycle", and flag the program locations that consistently leave stuff behind. The library should be able to capture a stack trace to give you the program location where the allocation was made. Otherwise it's useless in practice.

I'm very suspicious of code that deallocates all memory before process termination: usually it's just wasted time, and it prolongs system shutdown and is just bad UX. When the user hits the "Exit" button, make sure that data is safe (e.g. close sqlite files, save open documents - maybe just as "work in progress" that will be brought back the next time the application is used), and then call `exit(0)`.

In general, leak detection takes a bit more than just using a library that gives you a list of memory blocks allocated at exit. The library is a tool, that you, a thinking, reasoning human developer must apply to the problem :) Just as a hammer won't be useful by banging it all over the place (unless you got lots of nails to hammer!), so won't be a "leak detector" library all by itself.